# Java Bean that extends 2 other beans

Tags: java, javabeans

Im creating a Bean class called "worker". As i know, "worker" can extends from "person" (with basics data), but can not extends from another like "father". Bean cannot be an interface... So, what should i do?

Comment: rethink your design. not all workers are fathers

Comment: in java you can not extend two objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot extend two objects in Java, additionally not all Workers will be fathers. It may help to have your classes setup in the following fashion.

```
public class Worker extends Person {
  public Worker(boolean parent) {
   super(parent);
  }
} 

public class Person {
  private boolean parent;

  public Person(boolean parent) {
      this.parent = parent;
  }
}
```

Comment: May i create objects inside "worker", like person and father? -  I dont know if is correctly and im newbie in java yet.

Comment: Sure you could do that.